# Why doesn't MongoDB use sequential id's by default?

Tags: database, mongodb, nosql

Is there a specific reason for this? Security reasons? It seems so useful, and one could order elements without the need to use an array, or some other kind of order mechanism. Please enlighten me!

Comment: ...or if you downvote it, let me know why.

Comment: I have no idea what you're talking about, but thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(*I thought I'd be able to quickly find a suitable dup target or a documentation page...*)

> Is there a specific reason for this?

Distributed nature of the database. How do you maintain sequential integers between different shards without any duplication of ids or hits to performance? What about tens of shards? Hundreds?

Default generation scheme of an ObjectId allows to not care about coordinating shards at all. New ids can even be generated offline on the clients, and there are pretty good guarantees that such ids will be unique.

Comment: But why could one not simply use the data as the id like so `2018-03-03-15-03-23` with the structure `year/month/day/hour/minute/sec/miliseconds` (and then try to be super precise with the miliseconds)? Because of async problems?

Comment: edited and phrased it into a question

Comment: @R.Kohlisch millisecond-granular timestamp is not good enough. If you didn't know, part of object id is exactly that, timestamp in milliseconds. Then it has a few other pieces of data to improve randomness/uniqueness.

Comment: @R.Kohlisch: if my memory serves me, at one of the first awe-inducing public demos of mongodb, they built a cluster of like 100 super-beefy EC2 machines and were inserting millions of documents per second. MILLIONS.

Comment: yeah that makes sense! thanks a lot for answering this for me and not reacting like those 3 other people who just downvote but don't help out. Really appreciated, especially at the beginner level.